# How to do a descending for-loop countdown that creates <p> element with given number on each iteration?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This might seem insanely basic. But I'm struggling with this simple creation of an for-loop since no `p` Element is created on any loop-iteration. I don't know how to display the newly created `p` Element in my `div` Element (.output).

It should create an `p` element to my `div` on each iteration, showing the current value of `i`. When it's 10, it should say something like "Countdown has started" and at the end "Countdown Ended!". Here is a small sample (rest of html omitted):

```
<div class="output"></div>

<script>
let output = document.querySelector(".output");
output.innerHTML = '';
countBegin= "Countdown has started";
countEnd  = "Countdown has ended";
countBet  = "Countdown at ";

function countD() {
for (let i = 10; i<= 0; i--) {
    var para = document.createElement("p"); 
    if (i === 10) {
        para.textContent = countBegin + i;

    } else if (i === 0) {
        para.textContent = countEnd;

    } else {
        para.textContent = countBet + i;
    }
    output.appendChild(para);
}

}

countD();

</script>
</body>
```

I would expect to see at least one line as an output in the browser window but sadly there isn't any.

Comment: `i`  should be greater than 0 not less than 0. So your for loop should read `for (let i = 10; i > 0; i--)`

Comment: Thanks. I kinda got that wrong before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're looping from `10` to `0`, the loop condition should be `i >= 0`:

```js
let output = document.querySelector(".output");

output.innerHTML = '';
countBegin = "Countdown has started";
countEnd = "Countdown has ended";
countBet = "Countdown at ";

function countD() {
  for (let i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    if (i === 10) {
      para.textContent = countBegin;
    } else if (i === 0) {
      para.textContent = countEnd;
    } else {
      para.textContent = countBet + i;
    }
    output.appendChild(para);
  }
}

countD();
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Oh that's true. Thank you for the hint, it works perfectly now!